# Jquery returning RNan on data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a simple calculator using jquery. I have two select fields as seen here

```
 <label for="gold">
        <span>Choose Gold</span>
        <select name="ValOne" id="ValOne" class="DropChange">
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['paladium']; ?>">Palladium</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['nineK']; ?>">9K (white gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['fourteenkwhite']; ?>">14K (white gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['fourteenkyellow']; ?>">14K (yellow gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['eighteenkwhite']; ?>">18K (white gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['eighteenkyellow']; ?>">18K (yellow gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['twentytwokwhite']; ?>">22K (yellow gold)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_type_rows['platinum']; ?>">Platinum (950)</option>
        </select>
    </label>



    <label for="carats">
        <span>Choose Carats</span>
        <select name="ValTwo" id="ValTwo" class="DropChange">
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['twenty']?>">0.20 Carats (~3.8mm)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['thirty']?>">0.30 Carats (~4.2mm)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['fourty']?>">0.40 Carats (~4.8mm)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['fifty']?>">0.50 Carats (~5.2mm)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['sixty']?>">0.60 Carats (~5.4mm)</option>
            <option data-price="<?php echo $rs_size_rows['seventy']?>">0.70 Carats (~5.7mm)</option>
        </select>
    </label>
```

And I have this jquery that will do the calculation

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".DropChange").change(function(){
            var ValOne = parseInt($('#ValOne').attr("data-price"), 10);
            var ValTwo = parseInt($('#ValTwo').attr("data-price"), 10);
            var ValThree = $('#ValThree').val();
            var totalTotal = ((ValOne * 1) * (ValTwo * 1));
            $('#Total').text('Price: R ' + totalTotal + ' Size: ' + ValThree);
            $('#quote_btn').show();



  });
});
```

I have double checked and ensured that the values coming from the php are numbers, some have decimal places but they are all numbers.

When I run this Jquery I get a result of RNaN saying that it is not a number.

It works when I use value instead of data price, but I need my value attribute for some php that I will be using later on. So I needed to change it, however when I did it broke. Anybody know why that is? Or know of any theory as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the select element does not have the attribute, the option does. Select the selected option.

```
parseInt($('#ValOne option:selected').attr("data-price"), 10);
```

Comment: I feel dumb! It is late haha thank you for this! Will accept answer when I can